# The top of tableView has some empty area

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

The issue occurs as the pic .
[at the top of tableView has some empty area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AC5hJ.png)
The interface is that  viewController(embed  in navigationController).I put one tableView on it.And construct its constraints.But run the code ,and the issue occurs .I wanna try to use two methods to solve it ,but no any changes.

```
   self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = true
```

I adjust the constraints of tableView to superView,I set the constraint of top to -100,it works well.
The code as below:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData


class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var people:[NSManagedObject] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.title = "My book"
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

}
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
        return
    }
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName:"Person")
    do {
        people = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
    }catch let error as NSError {
        print("Cannot fetch \(error),\(error.userInfo)")

    }
}
@IBAction func addName(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "New name", message: "Add a name", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default) { [unowned self] action in
        guard let textField = alert.textFields?.first,
            let nameToSave  = textField.text else {return
    }
        self.save(name: nameToSave)
        self.tableView.reloadData()

}
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default)

    alert.addTextField()
    alert.addAction(saveAction)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)
    present(alert,animated: true)

}
    func save(name:String) {
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
        }
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Person", in: managedContext)
        let person = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: managedContext)
        person.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
        do {
            try managedContext.save()
            people.append(person)
        }catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not save\(error),\(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }

}



extension ViewController :UITableViewDataSource {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return people.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let person = people[indexPath.row]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = person.value(forKey: "name") as? String
    return cell
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try setting the `edgesForExtendedLayout` in your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []
```

Comment: It cannot solve this issue.On the contrary it causes new issue .Line disappear between the row of indexPath, flicker when click on the line

Answer (score 0):

You should put constraint for the `tableView` from storyboard and set `top space = 0`

Comment: Yeah I know the constraints  is zero to superView.top.

Comment: pls see the video here[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9x0953g6fvjrnwa/issue%20video.mov?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

try to implement

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return .min 
}
```

Comment: I find the issue is the top constraints of the tableView,I adjust it and then run the project ,that's ok.